# Socks5 Proxy Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, proxy

we are developing a socks5 source. but we have a problem.
we are using socket and threading libraries. 
but when too many users (about 200 connection) will connect to server we have this error:

> filedescriptor out of range in select()

in this line:

```
try:
    reader, _, _ = select.select([socket_src, socket_dst], [], [], 1)
except select.error as err:
    error("Select failed", err)
```

but cpu usage is just 3%!
server have too capacity but this error cause still running script.
what's the solution?
we should close threade? or solution is another?
thanks for your help. 
have a good time.

Comment: try to increase maximum number of open file descriptors in OS, for example in Ubuntu you can use ulimit or better prlimit for that. you can find alternatives for your OS.

Comment: This has notthing to do with CPU usage. It is a hard limit on the maximum FD value you can use in select. Possibly a Python limit rather than an OS limit. @GauravDhiman It has nothing to do with FD limits either.

Comment: Brief internet search suggests that python's `select` has a 1024 descriptor limit. I suggest, that you rewrite your code to use something else (e.g. `poll` or `epoll`). Also make sure, that you *immediately* close file descriptors when they are no longer used (garbage-collecting descriptors is ineffective, because GC might not destroy them quickly enough to keep up with client connections).

Comment: @user207421, I may be missing something but can you tell me why it has nothing to do with FD limits?

Comment: can you send me equal command with poll? @Gaurav-Dhiman